# How does the C function time() treat fractional seconds?

Tags: c

The `time()` function will return the seconds since 1970. I want to know how it does the rounding for the second returned.

For example, for 100.4s, will it return 100 or 101?

Is there a explicit definition?

Comment: It *could* actually return `99` if the clock resolution is nine seconds :-)

Comment: Generally speaking, it the time is, for example, 1514857893.927648 (where 1514857893 represents 2018-01-02 01:51:33 +00:00) , then `time()` will return the integer part with no rounding — 1514857893.  This is not mandated by the C standard; POSIX [`time()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html) says: _The time() function shall return the value of time [CX] ⌦  in seconds since the Epoch. ⌫_

Comment: if you care about fractional seconds, don't use time(), use clock_gettime() instead etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISO C standard doesn't say much. It says only that `time()` returns

> the implementation’s best approximation to the current calendar time

The result is of type `time_t`, which is a real type (integer or floating-point) "capable of representing times".

A lot of systems implement `time_t` as a signed integer type representing the whole number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT.

A quick experiment on my Ubuntu system (comparing the values returned by `time()` and `gettimeofday()`) indicates that the value returned by `time()` is truncated, so for example if the high-precision time is `1514866171.750058`, the `time()` function will return `1514866171`. Neither ISO C nor POSIX guarantees this, but I'd expect it to behave consistently on any UNIX-like systems.

Answer (score 3):

> [7.27.2.4p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.4p3)
>
> The time function returns the implementation's best approximation to
>   the current calendar time. The value (time_t)(-1) is returned if the
>   calendar time is not available. If timer is not a null pointer, the
>   return value is also assigned to the object it points to.

It's implementation defined, so unless you specify your compiler and operating system, the answer is "best approximation".

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a explicit definition?

No

---

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time

> The encoding of calendar time in time_t is unspecified, but most systems conform to POSIX specification and return a value of integral type holding the number of seconds since the Epoch. Implementations in which time_t is a 32-bit signed integer (many historical implementations) fail in the year 2038.