# How is time(time_t *arg) rounding milliseconds or second fractions?

Tags: c

I need to know what will

```
time(NULL)
```

return when current system time is :

```
1997-07-16T19:20:30.49+01:00
```

or

```
1997-07-16T19:20:30.50+01:00
```

Comment: What have your tried?  It depends on your platform.  After all`time_t` might not need to do any rounding - it could be a count of nanoseconds.  Look into `mktime()` (with zone change) or `mkgmtime()`) and `time()`.  Likely it just truncates the fraction

Comment: Hi @chux, I clarified my question. I did not try anything. I want to know what is the underlying strategy and what it will return for the two case I mention. I suspect a classic mathematical rounding, so the second will be exactly one second more of the first, but I don't know how to get the information without asking as I'm no C expert.

Comment: If `time_t` reports a count of  seconds (the most common `time_t`, it will certainly truncate,  else it could report that _now_ is tomorrow.  See extentions like `[gettimeofday](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) that explicitly provide the fraction.

Comment: @chux The `time_t` type [is defined](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/sys_types.h.0p.html) to be an integer count in seconds. It will not be nanoseconds on a conforming system.

Comment: @DanielH OP is asking how the non-integer actual time is rounded to the nearest second value:   up or down?

Comment: @DanielH C is not defined to be Posix conforming as per your link.  The C spec does say `time_t` must be a _real type_ which include `double, long long`, etc.  Further the C spec has "The range and precision of times representable in ... `time_t` are implementation-defined"

Comment: @chux Oops, my bad; this is only tagged [c] and apparently that’s only a POSIX extension.

Comment: @DanielH Many system's including non-Posix ones use `time_t` as a count of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  It is so common that many see it as a C spec as well as a Posix one.

Comment: @chux Yes; that’s part of why I’m surprised it is a POSIX extension. The rest is that the C definition of `time()` is so under-specified as to be almost completely useless without further information.

Comment: @DanielH There are many places where C under-specifies.  Certainly that was to embrace many various implementations circa 1989 when the POSIX `time_t` was not the de-facto standard.  Moving forward, changes to increase specificity would break C code and  prohibit improvements.  (What if we were stuck with 32-bit `time_t`: [Y2038 bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).  Sometimes the only way to rid legacy approaches is a revolution  or a new language.

Comment: @chux Adding specificity to the language doesn’t break existing (standards-conforming) code, but it does limit future features. I’d argue in this case it would be worth specifying that `time()` returns seconds, since `time_t` is already used for seconds in `struct timespec`, even if the zero point isn’t specified. But in any case, that’s not what the standard says now, so for a confident answer the question still needs to specify the system.

Comment: It really depends on the platform and implementation of time() commands on it.

Comment: See also [How does the C function `time()` treat fractional seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054495/how-does-the-c-function-time-treat-fractional-seconds#comment83081904_48054495)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `time()` reports a count of  seconds (the most common `time_t`), it will certainly truncate, else it could report that *now* is tomorrow.

C does not specify this, yet it is is the only reasonable implementation of `time()`.

See extensions like [gettimeofday](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) that explicitly provide the fraction and `time_t`.

---

A relatively new standard C function `int timespec_get(struct timespec *ts, int base)` does provide guidance that *likely* applies to `time()` in that the fraction part of *now* is truncated.

> If `base` is `TIME_UTC`, the `tv_sec` member is set to the number of seconds since an implementation defined epoch, **truncated to a whole value** and the `tv_nsec` member is set to the integral number of nanoseconds, rounded to the resolution of the system clock.

Sample usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void print_now(void) {
  struct timespec ts = { 0 };
  int base = timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
  if (base) {
    printf("%lld.%09ld\n", (long long) ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The standard doesn't specify the exact behavior, but the most likely behavior is to truncate any fractional seconds.

As an example, I ran the following on CentOS7:

```
time_t t;
struct timeval tv;
int i;

for (i=0;i<500000;i++) {
    t = time(NULL);
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    printf("t=%ld, tv=%ld.%06ld\n", t, tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec);
}
```

Which outputted the following when the second incremented:

```
t=1515099481, tv=1515099481.990469
t=1515099481, tv=1515099481.990469
t=1515099481, tv=1515099481.990470
t=1515099481, tv=1515099481.990470
t=1515099481, tv=1515099481.990470
t=1515099482, tv=1515099482.003241
t=1515099482, tv=1515099482.003250
t=1515099482, tv=1515099482.003250
t=1515099482, tv=1515099482.003251
```

Answer (score 0):

It will ignore NULL and return the time in seconds since the epoch start which is 1st January of 1970. 
Also, time_t is not the same as time function. milliseconds will be truncated, and the granularity of the timer depends on the settings as well as the hardware granularity. 
Some systems use interpolation to get soft-time beyond the seconds. 
If talking about time in Linux, see this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html, and there you will find clear distinction between the hardware real time and soft one. Go and see about jiffies, and how the hardware is set.